# Прокрутка до якоря на маленьких экранах

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день коллеги.
Есть сайт на bootstrap, он отлично сжимается на мобилке/планшете/нетбуке, без косяков.
Цель: только на маленьких экранах, нетбук, телефон, планшет, скажем перехожу я с "главной" на "прайс", нужно промотать страницу после загрузки мгновенно, а лучше плавно (есть куча всяких готовых скриптов в поиске, я уж не стал скидывать, т.к. он может не подойти для моей цели), к якорю например, в моем случае хорошо будет к H1.
Дело в шапке, на экране телефона только она и входит, лучше бы сразу проматать пользователям, к тому куда они шли.
Вот не знаю как реализовать сею штуку. Всё дело из-за того что это нужно только на маленьких мониторах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот например на jQuery и переделал, без клика, правильно? [Вот оригинал по клику ссылки](http://jsfiddle.net/bortvlad/f3mohxbo/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=f3mohxbo)
Всё работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
if ( document.body.clientWidth < 800 ) {
var destination = $(m1).offset().top -100; // -100 это отступ, навбар мешал
jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
  scrollTop: destination
}, 1000);
return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<h1 id="m1">Текст</h1>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>
<p>текст</p>


<a href="#m1" class="scrollto">ВВЕРХ</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Поиск элемента по id, дальше плавный скролл к нему, код выглядит примерно так:

```js
function scroll_to_elem(elem) {
  if(document.getElementById(elem)) {
    var destination = $('#'+elem).offset().top;
    var scrollTime=destination/1.73;
    $("body,html").animate({"scrollTop":destination},scrollTime);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id='h1'>Заголовок</h1>
```

Один минус, не уверен я, что на маленьких экранах анимацию не отключат. Во всяком случае, я обычно отключаю.

P. S. Да, вызывать функцию, например, так: scroll_to_elem(h1); где h1 - это id элемента, а не тег.

Comment: Попробую. А как это применить только на меленьких экранах? С ПК, с обычным монитором итак всё видно, прокрутка не нужна.

Comment: Что-то вроде: if ( document.body.clientWidth < 480 ) { scroll_to_elem(h1); }

Comment: это не работает =(